# Error in React-Native project, problem with the module 'make-plural'

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

I am having a problem when I try to run the app:

error: Error: While trying to resolve module `make-plural` from file `C:\Users\seiji\Documents\GitHub\Followmme-FrontEnd\node_modules\i18n-js\dist\import\Pluralization.js`, the package `C:\Users\seiji\Documents\GitHub\Followmme-FrontEnd\node_modules\make-plural\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`C:\Users\seiji\Documents\GitHub\Followmme-FrontEnd\node_modules\make-plural\plurals.mjs`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

I'm using:
"react-native": "0.72.6"
"make-plural": "^7.3.0"

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqugH.png)

Thank You!

I already tried install make-plural again.